# Search Bar - Filtering an Array of search terms for a Collection View Data Source

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, uicollectionview, nspredicate

I have a main plist file, which includes a collection views data source. The file has a Root array element with dictionaries for each category layed out in the following format:
[image: Example Layout]

The example shows one 'category'. These are loaded into an array for a `UICollectionView` and a property for access

```
self.mainDataSource = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

When I setup the cells I create a Dictionary instance for the `indexPath.row` and access the relevant objects. All this works fine.

**Issue**
What I am trying to do now is add a search bar. I have that all setup but I would like to filter the categories based on the word entered compared to the 'sub' array of search terms each category could have.

I have the following method which runs when they search, but I cannot figure out the best way to search the 'sub' array of the category Dictionaries.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate    = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[c] %@", searchText];
    self.dataSourceForSearchResult  = [self.mainDataSource filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate    = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY SearchTerms LIKE[cd] %@ OR ANY SearchTerms CONTAINS[cd] %@)", searchText, searchText];
self.dataSourceForSearchResult  = [self.mainDataSource filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

The trick was to include 'ANY' specifically for the LIKE to work. Then the name of the relevant sub array as key.